# Tomcat can't handle request with encoded chars in cookie

Tags: tomcat, cookies

I'm using Tomcat 8 as servlet container. One of my experiments gives interesting result.

I used "EditThisCookie" Chrome extension to add cookie with russian text (UTF-8). Request looks like:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/536.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.2045.89 Safari/536.17
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: test=Ð¢ÐµÑÑ
```

Server returns 500 error with blank page.

in catalina.log:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Control character in cookie value or attribute.
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.LegacyCookieProcessor.isV0Separator(LegacyCookieProcessor.java:748)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.LegacyCookieProcessor.processCookieHeader(LegacyCookieProcessor.java:545)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.LegacyCookieProcessor.parseCookieHeader(LegacyCookieProcessor.java:273)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseCookies(Request.java:2949)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getServerCookies(Request.java:2004)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.parseSessionCookiesId(CoyoteAdapter.java:1205)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.postParseRequest(CoyoteAdapter.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:513)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2463)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2452)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Does it mean that any stored XSS or "bad browser extension" etc can lead to denial of service?

Answer (score 1):

By default the Tomcat does not read unicode values. 
You have to expilictly set the URIEncoding attribute to `UTF-8`. You can configure that in `/conf/server.xml` under `<Connector>` element.

**Reference**:
[Tomcat configuration](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html)

Comment: I think the problem is those other characters are not URLEncoced. Probably, the extension does not support URLEncoding. You can try the same experiment from Java but encoding URL like this URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8").